# Javascript Grab id and innerHTML of PHP generated div

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to figure out on how to grab the id of a div from Javascript generated by PHP. Simply enough I have succeeded in doing so for a statically declared name for the id/name of that div.

Currently I'm trying to do the same thing but with a div generated with a `$val`, in this scenario it's hard coded but for later uses, it will be changing.

As of right now, the Javascript seems to fail after the call to grab the `document.getElementById` call.

Here is the code below

```
<html>
    <head>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                    function test(index) {
                            var value = "item" + index;
                            alert(value);
                            var tmp = document.getElementById(value).innerHTML;
                            alert("hello");
                    }

            </script>
    </head>

    <body>

            <?php
                    $val = 1;
                    echo "<div name='item.$val' id='item.$val'>Hello</div>";
            ?>
            <button type="button" onclick="test(1);">Click</button>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: What you mean with "_for later uses, it will be changing_"? The PHP code is run only once, just before the page is loaded to the client.

Comment: Your concatenation doesn't have the period in it: `"item" + index`, while your element has it in it: `id='item.$val'`. Did you perhaps think that that period was the PHP concatenation operator? It isn't when inside a string.

Comment: @Teemu I'm still a novice at PHP but basically the actual page I'm writing has page generated for an sql query call and php creates the rows, etc. I'm trying to assign those rows with an index value for later manipulation, in this case with Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the dot between item and $val

```
`
<?php
    $val = 1;
    echo "<div name='item$val' id='item$val'>Hello</div>";
?>`
```

Comment: Questions solved by fixing a typo should not be answered, they have close votes for dealing with them.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new here. Will do it better in the future. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Hey thanks this was the problem. I thought PHP used . to append variables.

Comment: Glad I could help. It does, but not inside a string.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
var value = "item" + index;
```

to

```
var value = "item." + index;
```

or change the php code from:

```
echo "<div name='item.$val' id='item.$val'>Hello</div>";
```

to

```
echo "<div name='item$val' id='item$val'>Hello</div>";
```